# Change source control credentials for an Xcode Server Bot?

Tags: xcode, git, credentials, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I followed Apple's directions for creating a new bot. During one of the steps it asked for the credentials for the source control system. I entered in a username/password not realizing that I wouldn't be able to change it easily in the future.

How can I change the credentials that Xcode Server uses?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a hassle but it is possible

1. Clone the repository by using new user's credentials
2. Open the project from within the new repository
3. Goto *Report Navigator* and edit the bot
4. On *Repositories* tab click on *Replace Repositories...* button
5. Xcode will fetch the new user name from `.git/config` file in the new repo and will give you a chance to provide the new password.

You can also alter the user in `.git/config` file of the current repo instead of cloning a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple help documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW1) for bots, the credentials are stored in a secure keychain on the server. It doesn't explicitly mention where, but look for a file called `*.keychain` (I'd expect `/Library/Keychains` to be one possibility; but it might be under the root of wherever the bots run). you should then be able to open that with `Keychain Access.app` to reset the credentials.

It's possible you might also be able to edit this from [the report navigator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/view_integration_results.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH4-SW1) with the 'Edit Bot...' menu, but it may not allow you to edit/change the repository details from there.

Comment: Note that the links are to the official Apple help documentation, which is also visible on the local machine when the docset is installed.

Comment: It's stored under that _xcsbuild user that Xcode server creates, although you might be able to get at them from an admin user, haven't tried.  When I run into that issue it's easier to let the bot create a new ssh key/password and change it in the git repo.

Comment: As with anything Xcode, deleting and starting again is almost always a faster way than trying to fix it :)